# static const GLchar *c becomes undefined

Tags: c++, opengl

the shaderLoader Function retrieves a String, i then convert it to const char with c_str(). But for some reason c is undefined. Any Hint?

```
static const GLchar *  c[1000];

*c =  shaderLoader("C:\\Users\\Dozent-01\\Desktop\\User\\CG\\bin\\vertShader.txt").c_str();

glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, c, NULL);
```

Comment: @Angew *c has type const GLchar *

Comment: What do you mean by `c` is undefined?

Comment: @user1767754 Are all these statements in the same compilation unit?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You're right of course, missed the `*`.

Comment: You should not be storing the pointer to a `std::string`'s `c_str (...)` return value. GL is going to copy that string immediately, so you can probably get away with it, but it is bad form.

Answer (score 0):

In you code include this file

```
  #include <GL/glew.h>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226171/setting-up-basic-shader-program-glchar-and-file-contents-undefined) post

Comment: Wouldn't this make the error `GLchar is undefined`? Of course the OP could mean that for all I know since no actual error was posted.

Comment: how c can be undefined. Only logical thing could be its not able to find the type of c.

Comment: Do not do this, `<GL/glew.h>` is a non-standard include. `<GL/gl.h>` would work, however.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `c_str()` behaves the same as `std::string::c_str()` does. That doesn't *covnert* anything. It gives you a pointer to the data stored in the string, which is only valid as long as the string itself remains alive and unchanged.

I will also assume `shaderLoader()` returns a temporary object. You take a pointer to its data and store that pointer in `c[0]`. At the end of this expression, the temporary is destroyed and thus the pointer no longer points to valid data. It's dangling.

You'll have to copy the data, not just store a pointer to it. Something like this:

```
auto str = shaderLoader("whatever");
c[0] = new GLchar[str.size() + 1];
strcpy(c[0], str.c_str());
// don't forget to delete[] the memory when no longer needed
```

---

Of course, there is also the question of why you have an array of 1000 pointers to `cosnt GLchar`. I suspect you actually meant `c` to be a buffer of characters where to store the string. If so, you'd change the code like this:

```
static const GLchar c[1000];

strncpy(c, shaderLoader("whatever").c_str(), sizeof(c));
```